# when i am installing ckeditor through composer i got error.how can i solve it?

Tags: laravel

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial>composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor
Using version ^4.7 for unisharp/laravel-ckeditor
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1

```
    - Installation request for unisharp/laravel-ckeditor ^4.7 -> satisfiable by unisharp/laravel-ckeditor[4.7.2].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - unisharp/laravel-ckeditor 4.7.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.0.3, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 10):

For laravel 7, this works:

`composer require ckeditor/ckeditor`

Credits to: https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor/issues/48#issuecomment-623553760

Answer (score 1):

Your laravel version is 6.* but `unisharp/laravel-ckeditor` support for laravel v5.*

Use laravel v5.* or install ckeditor without this package. You can install ckeditor manually. Copy all ckeditor files to `public/ckeditor` directory and copy/paste this code to end of your blade template where you want to use ckeditor. But this may not always work efficiently.

```
<script src="{{ asset('ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
```